# Increment variable inside HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple list in HTML and I'd like to add the numbers in javascript.

The li elements are hard coded (content changes every time) but the number of elements might change. That's why I'd like to dynamically add the numbers in the **number** class without dynamically rewrite the code in JS (I can't just do text(`<li>${num} ${variable}</li>`)

This is the HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="number">1</span> Something</li>
  <li><span class="number">2</span> Something else</li>
</ul>
```

JS
      const list = $('ul').length;
      let num;

```
  for (let num = 0; num < list; num++) {
    $('.number').append(num); // The output is 0123 for all the numbers...
  }
```

**Example:**

*I have 3 li elements* "1. Potatoes", "2. Carrots", "3. Cucumber";

*Elements change, now* I have 2 li elements "1. Potatoes", "2. Cucumber";

Comment: SO you do not want to use an ol?

Comment: Nope. I mean I definitely could but since I am practising JS I was wondering if there was a way using JS only

Comment: So how are you building the lis?

Comment: The list itself is hardcoded html, the list is repeated in every page (always the same, I use PHP include) but one element is deleted in every page, so I need the numbers to be dynamically updated

Comment: Seems weird you do not write it with whatever spits it out....

Comment: Basically it's a portfolio words list, the list is repeated in every page (always the same) but I dynamically delete the li element corresponding to the current project

Comment: So select the spans in the list and set the text.

Comment: If I do so, I get all the numbers in the loop 1234567 in my case

Comment: Because you are selecting all the elements and appending. I edited my answer to explain why yours failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(".number").each(function(index){
  let num = index + 1;
  $(this).text(num);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and it was very simple.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your solution does not work is you are selecting all the number elements on each iteration. `$(".number").append(...)` So on every loop you select al the elements and you append to them. That is why the numbers are added to each one.

You should be selecting the index you are on....

```
var numbers = $('.number')  // select all the numbers
for (let num = 0; num < list; num++) {  // loop
  numbers.eq(i).text(num);  // set the text of the current index
}
```

It would be better just use text() with a function if you want to go the jQuery way

```
$('.number').text(function(index) {
  return (index + 1);
});
```

---

Now your other options:

Best option, have whatever spits out the HTML generate it....

Next option, You could just use an ordered list and you would get the numbers.

Another option, you do not need JavaScript, pure CSS can insert the number

```css
ol {
  margin :0;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:li;
  list-style: none;
}

ol li:before {
  content:counter(li); 
  counter-increment:li;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Bacon</li>
</ol>
```

or if you really want JavaScript

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#myList li").forEach(function(li, i) {
  li.innerHTML = '<span>' + (i + 1) + '</span>' + li.innerHTML
})
```

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
}

ol li span {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol id="myList">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Bacon</li>
</ol>
```

if the spans exist, than just change the text

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#myList li span").forEach(function(span, i) {
  span.innerHTML = (i + 1)
})
```

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
}

ol li span {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol id="myList">
  <li><span></span>Apple</li>
  <li><span></span>Pear</li>
  <li><span></span>Bacon</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach for what you want is to create an update method that will reassign all numbers to the `<li>` elements, and call this method every time the `<ul>` is changed. Take a look at the next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    updateNumbers();
    
    setTimeout(() =>
    {
        $(".to-remove").parent().remove();
        updateNumbers();
    }, 2000);
});

function updateNumbers()
{
    $('ul li').each(function(idx, elem)
    {
        $(this).find(".number").text(idx + 1);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span class="number"></span> Something</li>
  <li><span class="number to-remove"></span> Something else</li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> Something else again</li>
</ul>
```